# Render .tpl.php from module using Drupal 7's hook_page_build

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a module `foo` and I've implemented `foo_page_build`. I want to use this function to prepend some content to the `page_top` region. So hard I have the following:

```
function foo_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['page_top']['foo'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Hello, World!',
  );
}
```

This works but now I want to load a `.tpl.php` and use this as the content to render. How would I do this in Drupal 7? Also, if this is the wrong hook to implement what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

hook_page_build is nice if you want to always implement content (even dynamic ones) at a position (region).

But maybe in your case, it is more easy to use the [Block API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/7.x) to define a custom block for your module which will print what you want in a region. You will then be able to manage on which pages, in which region, for which users, ...

After, to load a custom php template, you have to :

1/ Define a theme for your module, using [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function foo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'foo_block' => array(
      'template' => 'templates/block-foo',
      'variables' => array(
        'options' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

2/ Call the theme() function (Look for it in the Drupal API) and use what it is returning in the '#markup' attribute of your page_top element.

```
'#markup' => theme('foo_block', array('options' => $options));
```

The .tpl.php file will be placed in the sub-folder 'templates' of your foo module : /foo/templates/block-foo.tpl.php
And you will be able to override it in you theme folder.